# What metrics to use in regression if variance in output label is very low?

Tags: python, regression, statistics, linear-regression, metric

What metrics/method should one adopt in judging the error when variance is low in output variable. To give you an example : the output variable can be stock prices over a month, the variance generally would be low, (like 100.2, 100.23, 100.45, 101.02 etc.). A model made on this predicting 100 for each instance may give a great score (on a metric like R2 or MAE), but that won't be correct if you look from perspective of the error we wanted to see. How to handle this ? Do we normalize the output variable ? Or do we use a metric that increases the error exponentially on small deviation from true value, if so how ?

Comment: I encourage you to calculate the $R^2$ of the model that always guesses $100$. Comment with the number you get and your interpretation of that number.

Comment: an approach is to let the model know that $.2$ difference over a month **is a significant difference**. So transforming the input data to make these differences significant is one approach

Comment: @NikosM. What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Dave, I mean pre-processing the data to transform them is one approach that can make these small differences stand out for the rest of the pipeline